# Change background of the parent when hovering a child element

Tags: html, css

So i'm having the following menu.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Polish</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another one</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the links on the 1st  i have different background on hovering. When i hover the "Services" the 2nd  pops up and when i wanna hover a item from the 2nd  i want the link from the first  to stay active.

Like when i hover Services > Polish i want my Services' background to remain like it's hovered. Is that possible in css only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've made this thing from scratch, you can check it out

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZxUK/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZxUK/1/) (With `background` on parent)

```
.menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.menu > li > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.menu > li:hover a {
    color: #f00; 
    /* This selector will color all anchors nested inside li, 
       to be specific, please read the note below */
}
```

The crucial selector over here is this one, `.menu > li:hover a`, I am targeting `a` element which is nested inside `li`.

> Note: In Demo 1, I've missed out the `>` direct descendent selector,
>   make sure you use it to make your selector specific. So change this
>   `.menu > li:hover a` to `.menu > li:hover > a` - [**New Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZxUK/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css ..

```
ul ul:hover + a { color: red; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YZtgL/351/)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6bn8B/)

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Polish</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another one</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">More info</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```