# make parent anchor link color change on dropdown hover

Tags: html, css

I am a mega menu and i want color of parent menu to change to red/green when one hover over the sub-menu.

Right now i tried few things which didnt work may be i am doing something wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/13/

This doesnt seem to work

```
.nav > li > a:hover .dropdown  {
   padding:6px 12px 9px 12px;
    color:#444;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:0px solid #444;
    border-right:0px solid #444;
    border-top:0px solid #444;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#028F41;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

UPDATE:

This did trick for me

```
.nav > li:hover > a
{
       /*background:#028F41;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#028F41;
}
```

Comment: You want a solution in CSS or JS?

Comment: I Managed to pull it off with `.nav > li:hover > a
{
       /*background:#028F41;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#028F41;
}`

Comment: Show JSFiddle! I'd love to see what you wanted

Comment: reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401452/change-background-of-the-parent-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just made: http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/17/

I changed this code:

```
.nav li:hover > a {
    color:#f00;
    transition: 0.1s color ease;
}
```

It basically changes the color of the parent menu's link to `#f00` if the user hovers over one of the sub menu items.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Rick Peck, I managed to pull it off as well since you reply is correct so i will mark it as correct answer ..

Comment: Thanks buddy! Either way, it will be good to see your JSFiddle

Comment: Yes, i will but i have to wait for few minutes before systems allows me to do so.